# TeX4ht with Natbib, missing citations

Tags: natbib, tex4ht

I have read about LaTeX2rtf, but installing it on a Mac looks a bit intimidating, so in the meantime I am trying to use the workaround of using TeX4ht to convert my TeX into an ODT file and then saving to Word format. Anyway, in case this makes any difference I have been playing around with the SimpleTeX4ht GUI implementation of TeX4ht. When I convert the following code, the Tarski citation shows up as empty brackets [] in the output ODT file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
According to \cite{Tarski:1935}, you can have your cake an eat it, too.
\bibliography{bibfile}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

When I convert this file to HTML, the citations all look normal, but for some reason they get screwed up when converting to ODT. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe try to run bibtex again, natbib is working correctly for me

Comment: this is maybe same issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86728/2891

Comment: I'm closing as a dupe in the absence of any feedback: if this is wrong flag and I'll reopen.